# How many addresses are on a single CAN bus?

Tags: can

How many addresses exist on a single CAN Bus?

I am writing code, and I need to know how big to make my arrays. I don't know how many bits a CAN address is and whether any of them are reserved.

More specifically, I am interfacing with a vehicle [OBD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics) scanner. I just wondered if there was a specific number of possible ECUs on a bus.

Comment: Here is the first link on google when I searched for "CAN spec": [Click here](http://www.kvaser.com/software/7330130980914/V1/can2spec.pdf) The first non-title page of that first result has the answer to your question. The following pages have answers to the rest of your questions. It contains everything you need to know about CAN - all in one place, how convenient! Best of luck with your project.

Comment: I shall read the spec when I have time and post all I've learned.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because of insufficient preliminary research.

Answer (score 4):

None.  CAN messages don't contain addresses.  They do contain either 11 or 29 ID bits, but that's not what you asked about.  The electrical limit on number of attached nodes is totally different again.

You really need to **READ THE [SPEC](http://www.kvaser.com/software/7330130980914/V1/can2spec.pdf)**.